# On "Proving' Infinite Limits, And A Counterexample

Tags: calculus, limits, self-learning, limits-without-lhopital

The textbook I am using has come up with this method to prove why in infinite limits, the term with the highest degree will dominate:

[image]

It then goes on to say that at infinity, 1000/3x and all the other terms will be virtually 0. Therefore, the function will approach 1 (since it it lim x->infinity (1-0+0-0).

However, my problem with this, is for instance, take a function x+2/x-1. On the logic of the above, when we break it up, it is (x+2)*(1/x-1). At infinity, 1/x-1=0. So therefore, the limit is 0. But the limit of x+2/x-2 is actually 1.

We see this again we we take a function sin(x)*1/x. Again, at infinity, the limit should be 0, but it's not.

So what can explain this contradiction? Why is the above proof still right in these situations despite the examples below? How can we know that the proof above is universally true? And why is my logic wrong? Why is is x+2/x-1 not equals to 0?

Comment: The examples are different: in $\dfrac {(x+2)}{(x-1)}=(x+2) \dfrac {1}{(x-1)}$ you have $x$ also in the "part" $(x+2)$ and thus you cannot consider the limit for $x$ only of the other part.

Comment: While in the example $(1+\ldots)$ the first term : $1$, does not depends on $x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you elaborate what you mean "you have x also in the "part" (x+2) and thus you cannot consider the limit for x only of the other part."? Why can't you consider the limit for x only of the other part?

Comment: Consider $x/x$. We know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x = 0$ and that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x = \infty$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} x/x = 1$. You have to look at the term as a whole.

Comment: Because you cannot "compute" the limit for $\dfrac{1}{(x-1)}$ for $x$ to $0$ and then multiply the result for $(x+2)$, because also $(x+2)$ is "affected" by the operation of "computing the limit".

Comment: "Computing the limit" is similar to but not exactly as adding and subtracting and multiplying: you have to apply the "rules of the game" that you are allowed to use according to the theorems of calculus.

Comment: "*has come up with this method to prove why in infinite limits*" --- Instead of "method" you mean "example" (or "limit", or "calculation", etc.), and instead of "prove" you mean "illustrate" (or "suggest", or "indicate", etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the same method to $\frac{x+2}{x-1}$, what we get is\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+2}{x-1}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x-1)+3}{x-1}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}1+\frac3{x-1}\\&=1.\end{align}

And the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}x$ *is* $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. But why can't you do (x+2) * 1/(x-1)? Why would that yield a wrong answer?

Comment: @Mathguy: because $x+2$ goes to infinity and you get infinity multiplied by zero, which is uncertainty.

Comment: @Vasya Okay. But why is infinity multiplied by zero an uncertainty? And will infinity multiplied by any other value besides zero be acceptable? So will say infinity times 3 be acceptable?

Comment: @Mathguy: I follow these rules when dealing with limits: 1) infinity multiplied by a non-zero value is infinity (could be negative); 2) a non-zero value divided by infinity is zero; 3) zero multiplied by non-zero value is zero; 4) a non-zero value divided by zero is infinity (could be negative). If you have any other combination of infinity and zero, you need to modify the expression to fit one of the 4 cases.

Answer (score 2):

> [T]ake a function $\frac{x+2}{x-1}$. On the logic of the above, when we break it up, it is $(x+2)\frac{1}{x-1}$. At infinity, $\frac{1}{x-1}$ [tends to] $0$. So therefore, the limit is 0. But the limit of $\frac{x+2}{x-1}$ is actually $1$.

It's very good that you're noticing what seems to be a contradiction here.  The flaw in your reasoning is that the limit laws can only be used when the constituent limits exist.  For instance, the product law for limits is

*If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = M$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x) = LM$.*

You're trying to apply this law to the situation $f(x) = x+2$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$.  Yes, $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0$ and “anything times zero is zero.”  However, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is not a “thing”—it *doesn't exist.*  So we *cannot* apply the product law.

Students get confused because we say $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) =\infty$, and because there's an equals sign and a symbol on the other side, it sure looks like the limit “is” something.  But $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) =\infty$ is shorthand for an infinite limit.  There is *some* arithmetic than can be done with infinity, but $\infty\cdot0$ is undefined.

> We see this again we we take a function $\sin(x)\frac{1}{x}$. Again, at infinity, the limit should be 0, but it's not.

Again, the first factor has no limit as $x\to\infty$, so the product law for limits doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction at all.

The rule says that in a **sum** of terms you can neglect the terms that tend to zero (unless all the terms tend to zero).

The rule never said that this holds for a **product**.

For instance, consider $x+\dfrac1x$ vs. $x\cdot\dfrac1x$.

For increasing powers of $10$, we have

$$x+\frac1x=2,10.1,100.01,1000.001,10000.0001\cdots$$

which clearly tends to $x$, vs.

$$x\cdot\frac 1x=1,1,1,1,1,\cdots$$

which is intermediate between $x$ and $\dfrac1x$ and doesn't vanish.

For these reasons, you can write statements such as

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x+3}{3x-5}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x}{3x}=\frac25.$$